# Angular CSS class names collide with other components after Material Theming

Tags: css, angular

Hey there I've read many things about the style scopes for example https://angular.io/guide/component-styles. And somehow the point

> Class names and selectors are local to the component and don't collide
>   with classes and selectors used elsewhere in the application.

does not work for me.

I have a header-component with the css class `profileImage`. Then there's also the class `profileImage` in my user-component. I'm not using any custom encapsulation for any component. But still it's buggy now because the class `profileImage` of the user-component also uses the one of the header-component and only overrides the elements defined in both. So for example `position: absolute;` gets inherited but it should not.

```css
.profileImage[_ngcontent-bkm-c17] { //user-component
    max-width: 34px;
    max-height: 34px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.profileImage { //header-component
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 54px;
    max-height: 54px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
```

This happend after using angular theming. To explain what exactly is forcing this problem:

I got a `component-themes.scss`:

```css
@import "./app/header/header.component";

@mixin component-themes($theme) {
  @include tile-theme($theme);
}
```

It's included in my `material-themes.scss`:

```css
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
@include component-themes($theme);

.dark-theme {
  color: $light-primary-text;
  $dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 700, 300, 900);
  $dark-accent: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey, 400);
  $dark-warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 500);
  $dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
  @include component-themes($dark-theme);
}
```

And this is used in the basic `styles.scss`.

How can I prevent the described behavior while using component-themes?

The following code is for a `mat-menu` not a tile. I haven't renamed it yet because it's a copy of a tutorial.

header-component.scss (requested):

```css
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

@mixin tile-theme($theme) {
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
  $background: map-get($theme, background);
  $background-color: mat-color($background, card);

  .tile {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
  }
}

.toolbar-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
// verantwortlich für das Layout der Toolbar

.startpage:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.mat-toolbar {
  height: 7vh;
}

div {
  overflow: inherit;
}

.language-buttons {
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.language-buttons-login {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.navigate-buttons {
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.mat-fab.mat-accent {
  background: #3f51b5;
}

::ng-deep .mat-menu-panel {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  right: -16px;
}

.mat-button,
.mat-flat-button,
.mat-icon-button,
.mat-stroked-button {
  min-width: 1px;
}

.imageContainer {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  right: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.profileImage {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 54px;
  max-height: 54px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.font-awesome {
  margin-right: 19px;
}

// ::ng-deep .accent-tooltip {
//   background-color: mat-color($accentPalette);
// }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing your `"./app/header/header.component";` inside the `component-theme.scss`. This leads to the result that all styles from `header.component` will be global, because you are using the `material-themes.scss` in your global `styles.scss`.

So all styles you defined in `header.component.scss` will be loaded global, without that the angular compiler adds special attributes to ensure encapsulation. This leads to the result that other components, with the same classes will inherit all properties.

### UPDATE:

Original answer proposed to simply remove the `@import header.component` statement, but after OP added the header.component implementation it was obvious that this would not be sufficient.

To solve this the best solution would be to replace the `@import` rule with the [@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) rule. But as this feature is currently only included in DartSass and only since version 1.23.0, another solution is to remove the mixin definition from the `header.component.scss` file and move it directly to the `component-theme.scss`, and remove the `@import` rule.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I've done a tutorial where I need to import the path to the header-component if I want to use the component-theme.scss there.

Comment: Ok, then maybe I am wrong. But have your tried removing it? What happens?

Comment: Yes. Leads to a compiler error: @include tile-theme($theme); Undefined mixin.

Comment: have you tried using the `@use` rule instead of `@import` for the header.component? If you just want to use the mixin this should be sufficient and it does not load all style rules from header.component into the global style

Comment: Now the error tells me: @use is coming soon, but it's not supported in this version of Dart Sass.

Comment: could you show the content of your header.component.scss? Maybe it is possible to move your tile-theme mixin to avoid the import of header.component

Comment: ok as far as i see, it should be possible to move the tile-theme mixin on top of the component-theme.scss and remove the header.component import. Could you try that?

Comment: Seems actually to work. Added the mixin tile-theme below the mixin of component-themes and deleted everything with mixing and the theming import in the header.scss. I think that just means now that the defined class "tile" is accessible from everywhere right?

Comment: Ok then thank you very much. Maybe you should update your answer.